# SSRS Date Parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a table I am trying to view and it has column called `incidentdate`. I am trying to add a date parameter to show me the incidents that have been reported during a specific period of time, but the calendar that shows up in the top isn't allowing me to select anything.

All I need is a calendar with the years, months, and days to show up.

Comment: i have also added reportdate between -@startdate and the end date in my dataset proprieties , plus changed the datatype of the parameter to date and time

Comment: Make sure all your parameters are cased correctly in your dataset.  I don't see why the calendars wouldn't allow you to select anything.

Comment: this is my sql query if its gonna help - select 
IncidentNumber
,Country
from RaisedTickets
where IncidentDate between at StartDate and at EndDate , then i went to my parameter and changed the datatype to datetime. the question is do i have to declare anything in my database, or do i have to make any changes to anything apart from what i did

Comment: Your not actually using the word "at" before your parameters in that query are you? It should be the actual `@` symbol. (`@StartDate` and `@EndDate`).  In your first comment you indicated that at least.

Comment: yes im using @ i just cant type it twice here as it thinks im tagging someone :)

Comment: its driving me insane to be honest, i spent 2 days trying to get it sorted, now i cant even sleep

Comment: The calendar shows up, but you can't click a date?

Comment: Yes, its not grayed out, but it doesnt respond when i click it.

Comment: Solved- the filters werent using the same parameter, thanks timmy for your help